# Need to save file on Specific location

Tags: excel, vba

I am not able to save file on specific location with below code file is getting saved on recent location which was used.

```
    Sub SaveIt()
Dim dt As String, wbNam As String

wbNam = "Apple_"
dt = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\name\Desktop\Apple_date.xlsx" Filename:=wbNam 
& dt
End Sub
```

Please can you help me save file on specific loction.

Comment: you just need to add the path to the file name ```"C:\Users\name\Desktop\Apple_date.xlsx" ```

Comment: i tried that but it is giving me an error

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Should your format be `"yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm"` also?  And as @Warcupine says, the full path too

Comment: I am getting syntex error

Comment: well the path I put in the comment isn't a real path, you can't use that, you need to modify it to what your actual path is. It is also all a part of the file name parameter.

Comment: Yes, i have modified it and updated my real path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following and everything is working fine:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\" + wbNam + dt + ".xlsx"
```

Two things:

- "\" is a wildcard character, which means that it gives a different meaning to the following character. In case you want to use a backslash, you need to double it.
- Don't forget to add the extension to the filename.

Comment: it is getting saved into the last folder used